# How do I log process activity in linux with the least amount of interference (i.e. reduce observer effect)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, process, scheduling

I want to log the following parameters of a set of running processes (in R state) : PID, NICE, PRIORITY. I can use ps to get these, but I want to continuously log these parameters for a certain duration of time. So, I put ps in a C program which writes the output to a file and run it (which is straight forward).

As far as I understand, the C program will spawn its own processes which might compete with the pre-existing processes which I want to observe, causing context switches (which will be introduced by me). I believe anything which I will do to observe the above parameters will introduce some kind of bias.

So my question is, what's the least intrusive way of doing this?

Comment: How often do you need to poll? What about a cron job or even SSH from another machine?

Comment: I need a very high sampling frequency, ideally lower than the CPU scheduler's tick so that I can observe how the processes are being scheduled.